# Make Tag Clickable URL via js

Tags: javascript, html

Hi was wondering if i can get some help. ive got the following script that already gets the tag i'm trying to manipulate. I would like to make the tag or nodevalue clickable. How would i go about doing this?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var calMonth = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-header-title");
     var fcalendarLink = "http://www.google.com";
         for (var i = 0 ; i < calMonth.length; i++) {                         
              var h2Tag = calMonth[i].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
              var h2TagValue = h2Tag.innerHTML;
          }
          console.log(h2Tag);
          console.log(h2TagValue);
   });
```

Comment: You need to create an anchor tag inside your h2 tag.

Comment: you can also, do something like `$('the_id').click(function(){
 window.open...etc; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the onclick event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var calMonth = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-header-title");
     var fcalendarLink = "http://www.google.com";
         for (var i = 0 ; i < calMonth.length; i++) {                         
              var h2Tag = calMonth[i].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
              var h2TagValue = h2Tag.innerHTML;
added >>>     h2Tag.addEventListener('click', function() {
added >>>         alert('clicked');
added >>>     }
          }
          console.log(h2Tag);
          console.log(h2TagValue);
   });
```

You probably also want to use CSS to make the cursor change to the pointer. Something like this:

```
.h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`h2Tag.onclick = function() { //something here }` Try something like this

Comment: You shouldn't set onclick directly. It only allows a single event handler. Use addEventListener instead.